# Blazor: data binding requires additional trigger events

Tags: .net-core, blazor

UI Section

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect">AppId</label>
    </div>
    <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect" @bind="@appId">
        @if (appIds != null)
        {
            foreach (var appId in appIds)
            {
                <option value="@appId">@appId</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="appKeyFormControlInput">AppKey</label>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="appKeyFormControlInput" @bind="@appKey" @bind:event="oninput">
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" @onclick="SetAppKey">Get AppKey</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code section

```
@code
{
    private IEnumerable<string> appIds;

    private string appId { get; set; }
    private string appKey { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        using HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var result = await httpClient.GetAsync("API_ADDR");
        appIds = JObject.Parse(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())["content"].ToObject<IEnumerable<string>>();
        appId = appIds?.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private async void SetAppKey()
    {
        using HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var result = await (await httpClient.GetAsync("API_ADDR")).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
        {
            var app = JObject.Parse(result)["content"].ToObject<Application>();
            appKey = app.AppKey;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Expectation

When I click the **Get AppKey** button,
the value of `input#appKeyFromControlInput` shows
the appkey of current AppId(which in `input#inputGroupSelect`).

#### Actually:

When I click the **Get AppKey** button,
`input#appKeyFromControlInput` have no reaction;
When I click the **Get AppKey** again,
`input#appKeyFromControlInput` shows the correct appkey.

**Environment**:

1. .NET 5 preview 6
2. Blazor WebAssembly
3. windows 10 2004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code"

```
<label class="input-group-text" for="appKeyFormControlInput">AppKey</label>
```

Should be

```
<label class="input-group-text" for="appKeyFormControlInput">@AppKey</label>
```

AppKey is interpreted by the compiler as a string, whereas @AppKey is considered an expression that should be evaluated, the result of which is to be displayed between the opening and the closing tags.

You should also changed this: `private async void SetAppKey()`

to this: `private async Task SetAppKey()`

When you use async void your method does not return a completed Task object, and thus no one around knows when your component should be re-rendered. Thus, your component is not rendered on the first click, only on the second click, reflecting the values from the first click.

Always use async with Task, not with void.

Note: UI events such as the click event always trigger re-rendering of the component.